# Redirect stdout to a file and stderr to another file

Tags: compiling, directory

Use `find` to compile a list of all directories in `/proc`, redirecting the output so that the list of directories ends up in a file called `directories.txt` and the list of error messages ends up in a file called `errors.txt`.

I am new to the whole 'using terminal thing' and I would be very thankful if someone could help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is pretty simple stuff, try googling? Also, this is probably of topic on this site

Comment: What does your book / lecture handout / notes / videos say about redirecting output streams of a program?

Comment: have only had a 2 hour lecture and a few slides to help me out. (have tried out a few things like using '>' but I always get that I don't have permission to do what I want)

Comment: Just a hint: you need two separate redirections, one for `stdout` and one for `stderr`.

Answer (score 3):

That's simple. Use the following command:

```
find /proc -type d 2> errors.txt > directories.txt
```

or

```
find /proc -type d 2> errors.txt | tee directories.txt
```

More obout:

- [BASH Programming - All about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Comment: you beat me buy 15 seconds :-)